# How to update innerHTML number with each input submit?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to update the innerhtml with numbers from an input form

For example, if i put 3 in the form and click submit, the innerhtml is now 3.
If I put 5 in the form and click submit again, the innerhtml is now 8. JSFiddle attached.

```
<input id="itemName" placeholder = "Add an Item" type="text"/>
<input id="itemCost" placeholder = "Add item cost" type="number"/>
<input id="addItem" title="show" onclick="addItems()" type="button" value="Add Item"/>
<div id = 'totalCost'></div>

function addItems(){
    var total = 0
    var name = document.getElementById('itemName').value
    var cost = document.getElementById("itemCost").value
    total = total + cost
    var p = document.getElementById('totalCost')
    p.innerHTML = total
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/dr4carzr/1/

Comment: run parseInt on cost

Comment: I did, now it displays numbers correctly. But now it refreshes to a new number. For example, if I type 5 then 6 it returns 6. How do I get it to return 11? Is this a scoping issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to parse all the value with `parseInt`, and you have to retrieve the current value of TotalCost if you want to create a sum, instead function in your total value is set to zero with each new run (It must be zero only at the first run.)

```
function addItems() {
    var total = 0;
    if(!isNaN(parseInt(document.getElementById('totalCost').innerHTML))){
        total = parseInt(document.getElementById('totalCost').innerHTML);
    }
    var cost = parseInt(document.getElementById("itemCost").value);
    total = total + cost
    document.getElementById('totalCost').innerHTML = total;
}
```

Comment: It's still just refreshing to the latest itemCost that I put in, not the sum.

Answer (score 0):

`.value` will give you a string representation. 
So you need to convert them to a number first before adding it.

```
 total = total + cost;

 total = +(total) + +(cost);
```

Otherwise it would just append the values.

Also it is a better idea to attach the event handler outside your HTML, instead of providing an inline event handler.

```
var button = document.getElementById("addItem");

button.addEventListener('click', function () {
    var total = 0
    var name = document.getElementById('itemName').value;
    var cost = document.getElementById("itemCost").value;
    // Converting the value to a number 
    // before adding them
    total = +(total) + +(cost);
    var p = document.getElementById('totalCost');
    p.innerHTML = total;
});
```

**[Check Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/dr4carzr/2/)**